# ReferenceError: Can't find variable in function JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


var newPoint = "<div class='item-point' data-top='" + cY + "' data-left='" + cX + "' id='point" + random + "'>" +
"<div>" +
"<a onclick='test(1);' target='_blank' href='" + url + "'  class='toggle tooltips' title='" + description + "'  data-placement='top' data-html='true' rel='tooltip'><span class='pointFormat'>" + pointCount + "</span></a>" +
"</div>" +
"</div>";

$(".scalize").append(newPoint);


<div class="scalize"></div>

function test(variable) {
   alert(variable);
}
```

and it's not working. I have error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: variable.

I have error when I click on link (a href)

How to repair it?

Comment: You can't mix javascript and HML like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move all your javascript inside the `<script>` tag and keep the `<div class="scalize"></div>` HTML out of it. Like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scalize"></div>

<script>
  let cY, cX, random, url, description, pointCount = "Some text";

  var newPoint = "<div class='item-point' data-top='" + cY + "' data-left='" + cX + "' id='point" + random + "'>" +
    "<div>" +
    "<a onclick='test(1);' target='_blank' href='" + url + "'  class='toggle tooltips' title='" + description + "'  data-placement='top' data-html='true' rel='tooltip'><span class='pointFormat'>" + pointCount + "</span></a>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>";

  $(".scalize").append(newPoint);

  function test(variable) {
    alert(variable);
  }
</script>
```